# Can I travel to Italy from Nigeria with a copy of my expired permit and my original copy of ricevuta and this tiny slip with my passport photo on it?

Tags: schengen

I am traveling from Nigeria to Italy with a direct airline. When I applied for renewal of my EU family member resident permit I was given the ricevuta and I went to my comune for my appointment I got this tiny slip with my pics on it underneath they wrote" Attessa carta di soggiorno" and they took the original of my expired permit from me. So right now I have the Ricevuta, the tiny slip with my pics on it, my electronic Identity card, my passport and copy of my old permit.

Can I fly directly to Italy on a direct flight? And the last time I checked online my permit is been processed.